# Concatenar varios array y mostrarlos en PHP

Tags: php

Tengo que crear un array asociativo en el que se van dando de alta alumnos y debo mostrarlos en pantalla el problema que tengo es que se me sobrescriben las variables cada vez que las pongo
muchas gracias y perdón por mi desconocimiento en este lenguaje

Ejemplo al ejecutar:

Patricia saco un 6 en el curso de DAM

Si quisiera añadir otro usuario me sobrescribe el anterior escrito en vez de añadirme otro en la linea de abajo

Probé a realizar un contador del botón y meter el array en un for que se iba iterando las veces que le diese al botón, el problema es que haciendo esto solo conseguía repetir el ultimo usuario escrito el numero de veces que pulsara al botón, busque bastante en los foros pero la solución que ponían era guardarla en un objeto y no puedo aplicarlo en este caso, si fuese el array en java lo almacenaba en una lista, pero leí que las conversiones de arrays asociativos a listas no están bien echas en PHP así que se me acaban las opciones

Este es mi Codigo del formulario

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title>Formulario</title>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="generator" content="Geany 0.21" />
</head>
<body>
<!--Formulario-->
<form action="#" method="post">
<h1>Intriducir los datos:</h1>
Notas: <input type="text" name="notas" size="20"><br>
Curso: <input type="text" name="curso" size="20"><br>
Nombre: <input type="text" name="nombre" size="20"><br><br><br>
 
<input name="reset" value="Borrar datos" type="reset">
<p><input type="submit" value="enviar datos" /></p>
</form>




<?php
    if (isset($_POST['notas'])&&isset($_POST['curso'])&&isset($_POST['nombre'])) {
        $notas = $_POST['notas'];
        $curso = $_POST['curso'];
        $nombre = $_POST['nombre'];




        
        for ($i=0; $i < 1; $i++) { 
        
        $alumnos[$i]= array(
            "Notas" => $notas,
            "Curso"=> $curso,
            "Nombre"=> $nombre);

        echo $alumnos[$i]['Nombre'] . " saco un " . $alumnos[$i]['Notas'] . "         en el curso de " . $alumnos[$i]['Curso'];

    }



 



}


?>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Claramente se te van a sobreescribir los datos si solo haces el `for` una vez. Lo que debes de hacer es ir agregando los datos y creo que sería mejor usar el nombre como clave del array, para así poder hacer `$alumnos[$nombre]=array(...)`

Comment: si es correcto en el for le puse 1 pero anteriormente le pasaba un contador de boton el tema es que me repetia el ultimo array escrito y al final lo borre

Comment: Prueba con la solución que propongo, usar el nombre como clave del array asociativo

Comment: ¿Por qué no declaras los `name` de los `input` con array y luego trabajas el `$_POST` a nivel de PHP? Ten en cuenta que `$_POST` es un array, si organizas bien los `input` podrás obtener lo que pretendes además sin sobrecargar el código.